# I have created the setup.py, toml file and the module properly. But after installation I am not able to run the module

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I have created a reproducable project.

https://github.com/sagarpadiya6/python_cli

I am trying to create a simple CLI application and I am trying to install it as a cli tool. But the installation is success when I run the install.sh

But after that when I try to run the `flight_price` command I am getting command not found. For some reason its not registering the cli tool at all.

I am using macos. And I have python 3.9 installed using brew.

The `install.sh` script has the following line

`pip3 install -e .`

Here is my `setup.py` file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='flight_price',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['flight_price'],
    install_requires=[
        'click',
        'importlib-metadata; python_version == "3.9"',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'flight_price = flight_price.__main__:main',
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: The install should fail as the project named [`python_version`](https://pypi.org/project/python_version/) does not contain version `3.9`. You probably meant `python_requires='>=3.9'` as a separate keyword argument?

Comment: @a_guest I tried change it to as you suggested as well. It still doesnt work.
 `'importlib-metadata; python_requires=">= 3.9"'` Actually it gave an error 
`error in flight_price setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Parse error at "'; python'": Expected stringEnd`. I can completely remove that line as well it still doesnt work

Comment: `python_requires='>=3.9'` is a separate argument to the `setup` function, just like `install_requires`. It's not part of any string.

Comment: @a_guest I removed that line and added python_requires=">=3.9", separately. It now installed successfully but still command not found. Is it has to do something with having python installed using brew? I want to know if there is some Path variable that I need to set.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use a virtual environment and install the project inside that environment.